# How to determine communication range in Omnet++ 5.6.1 and Inet 4.2

Tags: omnet++

I use the following instruction in omnetpp.ini, but I get the "Unused entry (does not match any parameters)" warning.

```
*.host*.wlan[0].radio.transmitter.communicationRange = 500m
```

How to set the communication range? Also the interference range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting that warning may or may not be a problem (the IDE cannot always figure out the exact type of a module, so false positive warnings about unused parameters are to be expected). It depends on the rest of your code. The INET wireless tutorial should give you ample examples how to configure your wireless network.